# Django while True try loop in createview

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I hope I am not being a little paranoid but I am trying to make that when there is a record or customer number the next record is different from the previous one, the reason why I do it this way is because there will be many people capturing data at the same time every day and I do not want to throw a 404 error or something like that but on the contrary, in case there is already a record in the database retry and retry and retry again.

This is an example that I need to conclude to finish well my script, obviously before it makes a request to the database to verify the last record.

I know it is possible to do this with function based views but at the moment I am testing class based views, I have been doing this for several hours.

Any help is very important to me.

**Thanks guys.**

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Empresa(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    numero = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

views.py

```
from dataclasses import field
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import *

from aplicacion.models import Empresa

# Create your views here.

class CrearEmpresa(CreateView):
    model = Empresa
    template_name = 'crearempresa.html'
    success_url  = '/crear/'
    fields = ['nombre', 'numero']

    valor = 0
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        x = form.save(commit=False)
        x.numero = self.valor

        while True:
            try:
                x.save()
                return super().form_valid(form)
                break
            
            except:
                self.valor = self.valor + 1
                pass
```

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use the primary key, which is automatically unique as each Empresa is created?  You can make numero an [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#s-autofield), or you can make it a [primary key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields).  The code you have seems inefficient.

Comment: I understand perfectly your point of using the id or autofield in another field, the problem is that I am trying to give a customer number with this format, CLI-2022-001, CLI-2022-002. 

Before saving a record a lot of fields are filled in and I don't want them to have to retype them if it gives some error when saving, that's why the use of while true but I can't get it to work.